# How to set automatic height to anchor tags in jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm just starting using jquery mobile in a project. The problem I'm having is that every anchor tag I add, it sets its content to a fixed height value. I can't find a way to modify that behaviour.

An example of the code I'm using is:

```
<div data-role="content" data-theme="none" class="flex-container">
     <div><strong>Something</strong></div>
     <a href="#an-href" data-theme="none"><img src="../animg.png" alt="Icon" />A text</a>
</div>
```

Does it only happens to me?

Comment: `$('.ui-btn').css('height', '50');` this will help.

Comment: @Omar - I think there is no data-rel="button". It is a plain link

Comment: @user2409138 true, I didn't notice this. Anyway, you need to wrap your anchor with a div, and then modify that div's top margin or padding as in here http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/hzFK2/

Comment: @Omar - I think Joaquin is complaining that it makes the links the same size. I understand that he wants to get rid of it :)

Comment: @user2409138 let's see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends where your link is. Is it in a listview?

I tried to make two links with two different images inside (different size) and I don't see the behaviour you are describing.

Also, even though probably unrelated, # in links is normally used to link to another page.

See here - http://jsfiddle.net/TeNCE/

Can you either provide your jsFiddle or edit this one?

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="none" class="flex-container">
        <div><strong>Something</strong></div>
        <a href="#an-href"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/64/social_google_box.png" alt="Icon" /></a>
        <a href="#an-href"><img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/yooicons_set01_socialbookmarks/128/social_google_box.png" alt="Icon" /></a>
    </div>
</div>
```